# Getting true UTF-8 characters in Java JNI

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, java-native-interface

Is there an easy way to convert a Java string to a true UTF-8 byte array in JNI code?

Unfortunately GetStringUTFChars() *almost* does what's required but not quite, it returns a "modified" UTF-8 byte sequence. The main difference is that a modified UTF-8 doesn't contain any null characters (so you can treat is an ANSI C null terminated string) but another difference seems to be how Unicode supplementary characters such as emoji are treated.

A character such as U+1F604 "SMILING FACE WITH OPEN MOUTH AND SMILING EYES" is stored as a surrogate pair (two UTF-16 characters U+D83D U+DE04) and has a 4-byte UTF-8 equivalent of F0 9F 98 84, and that is the byte sequence that I get if I convert the string to UTF-8 in Java:

```
    char[] c = Character.toChars(0x1F604);
    String s = new String(c);
    System.out.println(s);
    for (int i=0; i<c.length; ++i)
        System.out.println("c["+i+"] = 0x"+Integer.toHexString(c[i]));
    byte[] b = s.getBytes("UTF-8");
    for (int i=0; i<b.length; ++i)
        System.out.println("b["+i+"] = 0x"+Integer.toHexString(b[i] & 0xFF));
```

The code above prints the following:

> c[0] = 0xd83d
>   c[1] = 0xde04
>   b[0] = 0xf0
>   b[1] = 0x9f
>   b[2] = 0x98
>   b[3] = 0x84

However, if I pass 's' into a native JNI method and call GetStringUTFChars() I get 6 bytes. Each of the surrogate pair characters is being converted to a 3-byte sequence independently:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_EmojiTest_nativeTest(JNIEnv *env, jclass cls, jstring _s)
{
    const char* sBytes = env->GetStringUTFChars(_s, NULL);
    for (int i=0; sBytes[i]!=0; ++i)
        fprintf(stderr, "%d: %02x\n", i, sBytes[i]);
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(_s, sBytes);
    return result;
}
```

> 0: ed
>   1: a0
>   2: bd
>   3: ed
>   4: b8
>   5: 84

The [Wikipedia UTF-8 article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Modified_UTF-8) suggests that GetStringUTFChars() actually returns CESU-8 rather than UTF-8. That in turn causes my native Mac code to crash because it's not a valid UTF-8 sequence:

```
CFStringRef str = CFStringCreateWithCString(NULL, path, kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
CFURLRef url = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(NULL, str, kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, false);
```

I suppose I could change all my JNI methods to take a byte[] rather than a String and do the UTF-8 conversion in Java but that seems a bit ugly, is there a better solution?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This is clearly explained in the Java documentation:

[JNI Functions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html)

> GetStringUTFChars
>
> ```
> const char * GetStringUTFChars(JNIEnv *env, jstring string, jboolean *isCopy);
> ```
>
> Returns a pointer to an array of bytes representing the string **in modified UTF-8 encoding**. This array is valid until it is released by ReleaseStringUTFChars().

[Modified UTF-8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/types.html#wp16542)

> The JNI uses modified UTF-8 strings to represent various string types. Modified UTF-8 strings are the same as those used by the Java VM. Modified UTF-8 strings are encoded so that character sequences that contain only non-null ASCII characters can be represented using only one byte per character, but all Unicode characters can be represented.
>
> All characters in the range `\u0001` to `\u007F` are represented by a single byte, as follows:
>
> [image: table1]
>
> The seven bits of data in the byte give the value of the character represented.
>
> The null character (`'\u0000'`) and characters in the range `'\u0080'` to `'\u07FF'` are represented by a pair of bytes x and y:
>
> [image: table2]
>
> The bytes represent the character with the value `((x & 0x1f) << 6) + (y & 0x3f)`.
>
> Characters in the range `'\u0800'` to `'\uFFFF'` are represented by 3 bytes x, y, and z:
>
> [image: table3]
>
> The character with the value `((x & 0xf) << 12) + ((y & 0x3f) << 6) + (z & 0x3f)` is represented by the bytes.
>
> **Characters with code points above U+FFFF (so-called supplementary characters) are represented by separately encoding the two surrogate code units of their UTF-16 representation. Each of the surrogate code units is represented by three bytes. This means, supplementary characters are represented by six bytes, u, v, w, x, y, and z**:
>
> [image: table4]
>
> The character with the value `0x10000+((v&0x0f)<<16)+((w&0x3f)<<10)+(y&0x0f)<<6)+(z&0x3f)` is represented by the six bytes.
>
> The bytes of multibyte characters are stored in the class file in big-endian (high byte first) order.
>
> There are two differences between this format and the standard UTF-8 format. First, the null character (char)0 is encoded using the two-byte format rather than the one-byte format. This means that modified UTF-8 strings never have embedded nulls. Second, **only the one-byte, two-byte, and three-byte formats of standard UTF-8 are used. The Java VM does not recognize the four-byte format of standard UTF-8; it uses its own two-times-three-byte format instead**.
>
> For more information regarding the standard UTF-8 format, see section 3.9 Unicode Encoding Forms of The Unicode Standard, Version 4.0.

Since U+1F604 is a supplementary character, and Java does not support UTF-8's 4-byte encoding format, U+1F604 is represented in modified UTF-8 by encoding the UTF-16 surrogate pair `U+D83D U+DE04` using 3 bytes per surrogate, thus 6 bytes total.

So, to answer your question...

> Is there an easy way to convert a Java string to a true UTF-8 byte array in JNI code?

You can either:

1. Use `GetStringChars()` to get the original UTF-16 encoded characters, and then create your own UTF-8 byte array from that.  The conversion from UTF-16 to UTF-8 is a very simply algorithm to implement by hand, or you can use any pre-existing implementation provided by your platform or 3rd party libraries.
2. Have your JNI code call back into Java to invoke the [`String.getBytes(String charsetName)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes(java.lang.String)) method to encode the `jstring` object to a UTF-8 byte array, eg:

   ```
   JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_EmojiTest_nativeTest(JNIEnv *env, jclass cls, jstring _s)
   {
       const jclass stringClass = env->GetObjectClass(_s);
       const jmethodID getBytes = env->GetMethodID(stringClass, "getBytes", "(Ljava/lang/String;)[B");

       const jstring charsetName = env->NewStringUTF("UTF-8");
       const jbyteArray stringJbytes = (jbyteArray) env->CallObjectMethod(_s, getBytes, charsetName);
       env->DeleteLocalRef(charsetName);

       const jsize length = env->GetArrayLength(stringJbytes);
       const jbyte* pBytes = env->GetByteArrayElements(stringJbytes, NULL); 

       for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
           fprintf(stderr, "%d: %02x\n", i, pBytes[i]);

       env->ReleaseByteArrayElements(stringJbytes, pBytes, JNI_ABORT); 
       env->DeleteLocalRef(stringJbytes);
   }
   ```

> The Wikipedia UTF-8 article suggests that GetStringUTFChars() actually returns CESU-8 rather than UTF-8

Java's Modified UTF-8 is not exactly the same as [CESU-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CESU-8):

> CESU-8 is similar to Java's Modified UTF-8 but does not have the special encoding of the NUL character (U+0000).

Comment: Any pointers on how to achieve the reverse? Converting native char* (say "Hello ") to Java string?

Comment: @skboro assuming the `char*` points to true UTF-8 data and not "modified" UTF-8 data, either 1) manually decode the UTF-8 to UTF-16 and then pass that to the JNI `NewString()` function, or 2) use JNI to copy the `char` data as-is to a Java `byte[]` array and then pass that to the `String` constructor that takes a `byte[]` and charset name as input, specifying "UTF-8" as the charset.

Comment: @skboro  If the `char*` points to "modified" UTF-8 data, then you can simply use the JNI `NewStringUTF()` function by itself.