# How to create UTF16 string in JNI for Java from C/C++?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I have a C/C++ char* string which has the smiley  but the rest of the content is in ASCII. For eg, *Hello World* .

When I try to create Java string in JNI using *NewStringUTF* and *NewString* the behavior is undefined.

What is the correct way of creating the Java string?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32205446/getting-true-utf-8-characters-in-java-jni

Comment: @KiriSakow Check it why? That question is about the the opposite operation.

Comment: How is the smiley encoded? (what actual bytes are used) In UTF-8 encoding it should be the sequence `f0 9f 98 8d` (4 bytes) And what do you mean by "the behavior is undefined"? How are you testing this?

Comment: Yes, the smiley has the sequence sequence **f0 9f 98 8d** when I used a text editor to view. Using NewStringUTF the jstring is sometimes truncated at the location of the smiley or sometimes before it. That's why I mentioned undefined. For NewString, I think I saw Japanese characters after conversion.

Comment: I was able to solve it. The char* points to true UTF-8 data and not modified UTF-8 data. So, I manually decoded the UTF-8 to UTF-16 and then passed that to the JNI NewString() function.

Comment: Could you post this as a (self-)answer? This could be useful for other people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **char*** that I had was pointing to **true UTF-8** data and not **modified UTF-8** data. So, I converted the string to UTF-16 first and then used **NewString** to generate the Java string.
For conversion of UTF-8 to UTF-16 I used [this library](https://github.com/nemtrif/utfcpp).

```
string line = myStringWithSmiley;
u16string utf16line = utf8::utf8to16(line);
return env->NewString((const jchar*)(utf16line.c_str()), utf16line.length());
```